# Seaborn Barplot estimator to calculate & plot category wise percentage

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am using the below code to calculate the percentage of each salutation. It is currently calculating the overall percentage of each bar using the length of each patch and divides it by the complete df length.

[image]

I am trying to calculate the percentage for each category separately instead of complete df. Like
90% Mr. is_registered = 0, 10 % Mr. is_registered = 1....

How to customize the estimator for the above scenario, or is there any other way that we can achieve it.

Additional* If there is a complete guideline for such cases with examples, please share. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include your code (with backticks) rather than a picture of your code hoping or expecting that people will type it in.

Comment: @hrokr em just expecting a solution or direction for it :) Not the Code!
Anyways will take care of it #next_time

Comment: What I was asking for was a minimally reproducible example. For more on that see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Under the Complete section you'll note it says: "DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."  -- That's what I'm asking for so I (and/or others) have to retype in what you did to then figure out what isn't working.

Comment: @hrokr thanks for the clarification, will take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab` and plot by pandas:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['salutation'], df['is_register'], normalize='Index')
   .reindex(['Mr.', 'Dr.',...]) # fill the rest of the order here
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Comment: is there a way to use the barplot estimator instead?